# Cannot access array field PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

Im returning an array full of 3 objects to a function where i simply want to access the 3rd tier data.

Now when returned, i can var_dump the whole array and i can see it, i can also var_dump the array plus the number of the object i would like to use and see it. An example below:

I use this code:

```
$data = Container::make_orderList();
    var_dump($data);
```

And i get this result:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(order)[63]
  private 'increment_id' => string '100000002' (length=9)
  private 'created_date' => string '2013-10-19 19:34:02' (length=19)
  private 'is_active' => null
  private 'weight' => string '20.0000' (length=7)
  private 'status' => string 'processing' (length=10)
1 => 
object(address)[55]
  private 'company_name' => string 'No Company' (length=10)
  private 'street' => string '20 Waterfall Way 
  Barwell' (length=25)
  private 'city' => string 'Leicester' (length=9)
  private 'region' => string 'Leicestershire' (length=14)
  private 'postcode' => string 'LE9 8EH' (length=7)
2 => 
object(address)[54]
  private 'company_name' => string 'CRanbri Web Solutions' (length=21)
  private 'street' => string '4 Turner Drive
  Hinckley' (length=23)
  private 'city' => string 'Leciester' (length=9)
  private 'region' => string 'LEicesterhsire' (length=14)
  private 'postcode' => string 'LE10 0gu' (length=8)
  private 'country_id' => string 'GB' (length=2)
```

and with:

```
$data = Container::make_orderList();
    var_dump($data[0]);
```

I get this result:

```
object(order)[63]
 private 'increment_id' => string '100000002' (length=9)
 private 'created_date' => string '2013-10-19 19:34:02' (length=19)
 private 'is_active' => null
 private 'weight' => string '20.0000' (length=7)
 private 'status' => string 'processing' (length=10)
 private 'shipping_address_id' => string '4' (length=1)
 private 'billing_address_id' => string '3' (length=1)
 private 'shipping_method' => string 'flatrate_flatrate' (length=17)
 private 'shipping_description' => string 'Flat Rate - Fixed' (length=17)
 private 'order_id' => string '2' (length=1)
 private 'gift_message' => null
```

This is great and what i need, but what im having trouble doing is accessing the individual fields of the array say for example the 'increment_id' field.

I have tried:

```
$data = Container::make_orderList();
    var_dump($data[0]->increment_id);
```

But i get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property order::$increment_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_soap_client\fulfilment\soap\views\view.content.php on line 20

I don't suppose you could help me put with how i should access these fields?

Thanks

Comment: as error says, your fields are `private` so you should make getters/setters or make them `public`

Comment: the php syntax does not accept this format, you should first assign $data[0] to a varible like $obj, then access its fields:$obj->increment_id also your fields are private and are not visible outside of the class

Comment: Private means that you cant access them from outside. Thats why its private. You have to make them public.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys, all set to public now! blonde moment i think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the fields of your object public or create getters and/or setters for the fields. You might want to take a look at the documentation about [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) of properties and methods in PHP.